# Separate start directory for each client

Tags: c, sockets, select

I have a select based server system, where I can manage multiple clients. The server automatically reads and responds to the client, which is great. But there's a minor issue. For instance user#1 changes directory (coded with `chdir`), all of the other users are affected by this change. I really do wish that prevented for happening.

Comment: I put the code back because it helped me understand what you were asking.

Comment: @ams Ah I see. But case closed, I believe. As I commented below, I'm using Struct. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to solve this:

1. Fork off a separate process to handle each connection. This process can have its own state, including current working directory. The disadvantages are that you'll need to refactor your code quite a lot, and if you have a lot of concurrent connections then it can be a performance problem. This is harder on Windows that *nix, but not impossible.
2. Keep the current directory as a per-connection setting *within* your program, and (re)set the directory before executing *every* user command.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to make a struct with an ID and a Workspace, where all of the data will be managed and stored... If this is possible.